# Double click quickly on the entity save form two entity get created

Tags: entities

I am using Entity Construction Kit 7.x-2.0-rc2. I have created one entity type with some manage field as title,message. if i double click quickly on creating entity then it will save entity form two or more entities get created.

Comment: FYI [here's the issue on d.o.](https://www.drupal.org/node/1705618)

Comment: @Andy above link is drupal core issue for node. it will not sort out issue for eck(entity construction kit) because when we create node then a file misc/form.js is called but in case of entity it will not call so this issue will not sorted out with above link solution.

Comment: I don't think so. If you look [at the fix for D8](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/drupal/commit/?id=502e953) and the [proposed library to use with D7/D6](https://github.com/sun/jquery-form-submit-single), I think it's a general issue with a general solution. (Though I haven't read every comment on the issue!)

Comment: @andy,Clive this is not duplicate question this is purely different from core node submit issue. This is related with eck.

Comment: @Fawwad The duplicate isn't specific to node forms, it's about stopping a double-submit on _any_ form. The solution provided there (and here) works for any form, including ECK forms. There's no other possible solution to the problem, so even if you don't want to use that module you'll still need to use pretty much exactly the same code in a custom module anyway, so the answer is the same

Answer (score 1):

Try [Hide Submit](https://www.drupal.org/project/hide_submit)

> Features:
>
> Hide or disable the submit button after it has been clicked
>
> Display a message and/or image while waiting